# Does returning a reference from a unique_ptr sometimes create a copy of its object?

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference, copy-constructor, unique-ptr

The code below uses a reference from a unique_ptr in a map to populate an object. A later reference from the unique_ptr shows no trace of the updates.

**XSSFWorkbook::CreateCellStyle** is a client for the **XSSFCellStyle::CreateCellStyle** factory function.  It stores the **XSSFCellStyle** object in **UPTR__CellStylesMap** and returns a reference to it.

**XSSFWorkbook::GetStylesheetXml()** later obtains a reference to each **XSSFCellStyle** and uses it to output the XML.

**XSSFWorkbook.cpp**

```
//  ****************************************************************************
//  CreateCellStyle
//  ****************************************************************************
    XSSFCellStyle&
    XSSFWorkbook::CreateCellStyle()
    {   map<int, unique_ptr<XSSFCellStyle>>::iterator   iter__CellStylesMap;
        unique_ptr<XSSFCellStyle>                       uptr__XSSFCellStyle     = nullptr;

        uptr__XSSFCellStyle = XSSFCellStyle::CreateCellStyle();
        UPTR__CellStylesMap->insert( make_pair( UPTR__CellStylesMap->size(), move( uptr__XSSFCellStyle ) ) );
        iter__CellStylesMap = UPTR__CellStylesMap->find( UPTR__CellStylesMap->size() - 1 );
        return *iter__CellStylesMap->second
    }

//  ****************************************************************************
//  GetStylesheetXml
//  ****************************************************************************
    string
    XSSFWorkbook::GetStylesheetXml()
    {   map<int, unique_ptr<XSSFCellStyle>>::iterator   iter__CellStylesMap;
        string                                          str___CellStyleXfsXml   = "";

//      ========================================================================
//      Build the XML for the Cell Styles.
//      ========================================================================
        if( UPTR__CellStylesMap->size() > 0)
        {   str___CellStyleXfsXml   += "<cellStyleXfs count=\"" + ConvertToString( UPTR__CellStylesMap->size() ) + "\">";
            iter__CellStylesMap      = UPTR__CellStylesMap->begin();
            while( iter__CellStylesMap != UPTR__CellStylesMap->end() )
//          {   str___CellStyleXfsXml           +=  iter__CellStylesMap->second->GetXml();
            {   XSSFCellStyle& xssf__CellStyle   = *iter__CellStylesMap->second;
                str___CellStyleXfsXml           +=  xssf__CellStyle.GetXml();
                iter__CellStylesMap++;
            }
            str___CellStyleXfsXml   += "</cellStyleXfs>";
...
    }

/   ****************************************************************************
//  GetXml
//  ****************************************************************************
    string
    XSSFWorkbook::GetXml()
    {   string  str___WorkbookXml   = "";

        str___WorkbookXml   += "<workbook><sheets><sheet name=\"1\" sheetId=\"1\" r:id=\"rId1\" /></sheets></workbook>";
        str___WorkbookXml   += GetStylesheetXml();
...
        return str___WorkbookXml;
    }
```

This code in **WinMain** calls **XSSFWorkbook::GetXml()** which then calls **XSSFWorkbook::GetStylesheetXml()** to obtain a reference to the **XSSFCellStyle** object and print its XML.

```
XSSFCellStyle xssf__CellStyle = xssf__Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
xssf__CellStyle.SetApplyAlignment( true );
uptr__OoxmlTester->SetOoxml( xssf__Workbook.GetXml() );
```

It returned the default values set in the **XSSFCellStyle::XSSFCellStyle()** initialization list, even though cout statements revealed that **XXSFCellStyle::SetApplyAlignment()** set the ApplyAlignment property properly.

But using the **XSSFCellStyle** reference instead

```
uptr__OoxmlTester->SetOoxml( xssf__CellStyle.GetXml() );
```

*did* return the updated value (of course).

Changing **XSSFWorkbook::CreateCellStyle()** so that it returns a raw pointer

```
XSSFCellStyle*
XSSFWorkbook::CreateCellStyle()
...
return iter__CellStylesMap->second.get();
```

and **WinMain** likewise

```
XSSFCellStyle* ptr___CellStyle = xssf__Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
ptr___CellStyle->SetApplyAlignment( true );
uptr__OoxmlTester->SetOoxml( xssf__Workbook.GetXml() );
```

retured the updated values, showing that the pointer version does actually update the **XSSFCellStyle** instance in **UPTR__CellStylesMap**.

I don't see how the reference version of **XSSFWorkbook::CreateCellStyle()** gives me a reference to an **XSSFCellStyle** object not in **UPTR__CellStylesMap** (a copy?), whereas the same code in **XSSFWorkbook::GetCellStyleXml()** *does* obtain a reference to an **XSSFCellStyle** object in **UPTR__CellStylesMap**.

Because there is no such thing as a NULL **XSSFCellStyle**, I've abandoned the reference version in favor of the unique_ptr version, but I'd still like to know how never to re-create this mystery.

P.S. My coding style breaks with convention and upsets some people.  Please don't let it bother you.

Comment: Can you produce an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This is way too much code for what should be a fairly concise question.

Comment: True; it took me 6 hours to post this.  I won't have time to work on an MVCE until this weekend.

Comment: I recommend you [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiYliKliFvs) talk, where among other things they argue that comments such as `//  GetXml` on a method called `GetXml` are not nice at all.

Comment: I cut out the code that was unrelated to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are creating a copy in this line:

```
XSSFCellStyle xssf__CellStyle = xssf__Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
```

It should be noted that the copy is not, as you implied, created by returning the reference, but rather by initializing a new value with the returned reference.
If you want to avoid a copy you should either store the result in a reference or in a pointer.

```
XSSFCellStyle& xssf__CellStyle = xssf__Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
//or this
XSSFCellStyle* ptr__CellStyle = &xssf__Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
```

If you want to avoid accidentally copying then you should consider deleting the copy-constructor of `XSSFCellStyle` like this:

```
XSSFCellStyle( const XSSFCellStyle&) = delete;
```

I know it's a stylistic decision, but I don't think that a function beginning with `Create` should return a reference.

Comment: I got so close. It looks like the naming convention for a function that returns a reference is "get...()".

Comment: @pbyhistorian yes I would most likely associate returning a reference with an accessor, but in your case it is necessary to communicate that a new Object is create too, so I guess `getNewXYZ()` is what would surprise me the least. But thinking about it, `Create` isn't really that bad. Either way, documenting the ownership (or in this case lack thereof)/ lifetime of the returned object reference (or pointer) in the function documentation is probably more important than the name.